# How steep is the slope?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The height of a certain hill (in feet) is given by

$h(x, y) = 10(2xy − 3x^2 − 4y^2 − 18x + 28y + 12)$,

where $y$ is the distance (in miles) north, $x$ the distance (in miles) east of South Hadley.

How steep is the slope at $y=1$, $x=1$?

**My thoughts:**

The directional derivative is given by $\nabla h(1, 1)\cdot\mathbf{u}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit vector. But what do I take as $\mathbf u$?

Comment: Yes, in 2 variable function, you can find gradient in particular Direction. Slope word is not used in this case. The gradient in general, varies according to the direction of unit vector.

Comment: So, is the question asking for the maximal value of the slope, which would be $\nabla f(1, 1)$?

Comment: I understand the question is "how steep in the steepest direction", see on a slope it is not equally steep in different directions, for example if you walk "transversely" you are not gaining or losing altitude. So in this case you choose $u=\nabla h/|\nabla h|$, recall that $h$ increases the fastest in the $\nabla h$ direction. So the answer is $|\nabla h|(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, both of you!